# how to loop over results using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I was doing this successfully with python and beautiful soup but now I am trying to port it into Node.js

My issues is that the loop is not putting each item into its own object in the array, but just putting everything into one like this:

```
[
  {
    numbers: '123987456789',
    letters: 'ABCDEFG'
  }
]
```

Instead of:

```
[
  {
    numbers: '123',
    letters: 'A'
  },
  {
    numbers: '987',
    letters: 'B
  }
]
```

The tricky part is that the div's have the same ID so I needed to get a particular one within the array of divs.

In Python I did this and then use `append` to add the items to an empty list

```
myDivs = soup.select('#my-divs')[2]
numbers = myDivs('text.numbers')
labels = myDivs('text.labels')
```

Node.js

```
exports.scrapeData = async (req, res) => {
  const html = await Axios.get(
    "https://example.com"
  );
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html.data);
  let tests = [];
  $("#my-divs:eq(2)").each((i, elem) => {
    tests.push({
      numbers: $(elem).find("text.numbers").text(),
      labels: $(elem).find("text.labels").text(),
    });
  });

  console.log(tests);
```

html:

```
  <div id="my-divs">
      <text class="numbers">123</text>
      <text class="labels">A</text>
      <text class="numbers">987</text>
      <text class="labels">B</text>
  </div>
  <div id="my-divs">
      <text class="numbers">567</text>
      <text class="labels">C</text>
      <text class="numbers">543</text>
      <text class="labels">D</text>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this approach: Find all `.numbers`, and and for each of them, return an object containing its own `.text()` and the immediately following `.labels` using Cheerio's `.next()`:

```
exports.scrapeData = async (req, res) => {
  const html = await Axios.get("https://example.com");
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html.data);

  const tests = $("#my-divs:eq(2)").find(".numbers").map(function () {
    return {
      numbers: $(this).text().trim(),
      labels: $(this).next(".labels").text().trim(),
    }
  }).toArray();

  console.log(tests);
});
```

Cheerio's `.map()` allows using `this` contextually, and Cheerio's `.toArray()` extracts the underlying JavaScript array from the Cheerio object.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. When I try it though I get exactly the same problem as before where everything is in one single object `[
  {
    numbers: '123987456789',
    letters: 'ABCDEFG'
  }
]`

Comment: Perhaps my explanation was wrong (probably).`#my-divs` is not actually an array but a div with an ID that is used multiple times. So, there are 5 divs with the same ID (not my design) and I need to get the data from only one of those divs.

Comment: Yes.  Can you add the relevant HTML snippet to your question?

Comment: Added html. Hopefully that is enough?

Comment: Yes, that works better. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much! After changing the code I still get the same issue ie: everything together in one object.

Comment: @Waterfall *Now* I get it, took me a moment. Changed answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using spreads and index pairing like a `zip` function:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const html = `
<div id="my-divs">
  <text class="numbers">123</text>
  <text class="labels">A</text>
  <text class="numbers">987</text>
  <text class="labels">B</text>
</div>
<div id="my-divs">
  <text class="numbers">567</text>
  <text class="labels">C</text>
  <text class="numbers">543</text>
  <text class="labels">D</text>
</div>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const numbers = [...$("#my-divs:eq(1) .labels")];
const data = [...$("#my-divs:eq(1) .numbers")].map((e, i) => ({
  numbers: $(numbers[i]).text(),
  letters: $(e).text(),
}));
console.log(data);
// => [ { numbers: 'C', letters: '567' }, { numbers: 'D', letters: '543' } ]
``
```